# why does cocos 2d-x v3 use pointers so often in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, auto

I am new to c++ programmer coming from Java and I adore c++. To my knowledge I thought pointers usually point to the address of an object that is already initialized. In coocos2d very often in-order to create an object you would write something along the lines of:

```
      auto mysprite=Sprite::create("image.png");
```

and to use a method for mysprite you would write:

```
   mysprite->mymethod();
```

my basic knowledge of pointers is that they are used something like so :

```
   int* mypoint;
   int x=7;
   mypoint=&x;
```

coming from java this is quite confusing why wouldn't or when would you create an object like this calling the class itself like so:

```
      Sprite* mysprite=Sprite::create("image.png");
       mysprite.mymethod();
```

I figured this Would be important to fully understand since many of the constructors in the cocos2d library takes pointers in the constructors and I find myself blindly writing auto as the identifier for my variables yet im not sure why. Thank you for the clarification in advance.

Comment: In your last code block `mysprite` is still a pointer...

Comment: hmm that is correct  so i guess my question is why would i use "->" instead of "."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ pointers occupy much the same position as object references (aka objects) in Java. In Java, you do something like:

```
String foo = new String;
```

When you do this, `foo` is really a pointer underneath the hood. You can do this for example:

```
String foo = new String;
String bar = foo;
```

And that doesn't create a copy of a the `String`, it just sets `bar` to refer to the same `String` as foo. For `String` this isn't such an important distinction since the `String` type in Java is immutable. But, for something like this:

```
int[][] foo = new int[5][5];
int[][] bar = foo;
bar[0][0] = 6;
```

Then it matters. When you set `bar[0][0]` you also set `foo[0][0]` because they refer to the same array. `bar` and `foo` are references to something, not values. In Java this is kind of obscured because the only values you can have are primitive types like `int` or `float`.

In C++ you can have values that are complex types. For example, if you say this:

```
struct point_2d {
   int x, y;
};

void a_function()
{
    point_2d p1;
    point_2d p2 = p1;
    p2.x = 5;
}
```

First, notice the lack of `new`. In C++, `new` is used to create things 'on the heap' which is where Java puts **everything** that isn't a primitive type. In C++, `p1` and `p2` up there are in the same place that Java would put `int x;` and `int y;`. On the stack. They are destroyed on function exit, and not because all references to them go away so they're garbage collected. They go away regardless.

Also, when you did `p2.x = 5;`, the value of `p1.x` did not change. When you created `p2`, you copied the value from `p1`. You didn't create another reference to it. So the values exist independently of each other.

Now, why does your library toss pointers all over? Well, pointers in C++ are like Java references (in other words, every single variable in Java that isn't a primitive type). But, since the default in C++ is not to be a reference (unlike Java) you have to be explicit about when you have one and when you don't.

In your specific case, somewhere inside the `Sprite::create` function the library is doing something like `Sprite *newsprite = new Sprite;`. So, it's creating a `Sprite` on the heap. Likely, it's actually a class derived from `Sprite` not a `Sprite` itself, but the same basic idea.

You keep having to use `->` and not `.` because `->` is used to access members of a class through a pointer, and `.` is used to access them through a value. Since Java doesn't have that distinction (anything you would use `.` for is a pointer already) it doesn't have the two different syntaxes.

This means that you will have to do `delete mysprite;` at some point in time to free up the memory it's using. Unlike Java, C++ does not do memory management (aka garbage collection) for you.

It also seems that this cocos 2d-x v3 library you're using has a fairly old-style interface. In modern C++ you are discouraged from using bare pointers for a variety of different reasons. That library should be returning a `::std::shared_ptr<Sprite>` or a `::std::unique_ptr<Sprite>`. But that's beyond the scope of this question.

But, the library does have to use pointers. A `Sprite` is likely fairly expensive to copy (especially since the library seems to be using an older style of interface and so likely does not take advantage of nifty features like move constructors) and so the library wants to allocate one on the heap and pass you a reference (aka a pointer) because those are cheap to copy.

Also, try not using `auto` until you understand what's going on. The automatic type deduction of C++ is very nice in a variety of situations, especially when using container classes that can sometimes have very complex type names for iterators and such. But it lets you use types without really knowing which ones you're using. And in your case, at the level of experience you have, with the library you're trying to use, that's not so good.

This topic is really too complex for a StackOverflow answer. But this is the basics of what's going on and should provide

Comment: wow thank you so much I understand it much clearer now. Coding is much easier when you actually understand the backbone of what you are typing in.

Comment: @Cosmik11 - Wait til you start trying to understand C++ references. They are exactly like pointers really, except they can't point to `nullptr` and you use `.` with them and they otherwise behave similarly to values. When to use a pointer and when to use a reference in a C++ interface is a careful design decision, but the implications are mostly for people, as far as the code the compiler generates, it doesn't matter a whole lot. (Except, unlike a pointer, a reference is constant, it refers to the same thing forever after its creation).

Answer (score 1):

> my question is why would i use "->" instead of "."

Because the thing on the left is a pointer.

If `a` is a pointer then `a->b` is the same as `(*a).b` except it looks nicer.

If `a` is a pointer then `a.b` is an error.

Comment: I see I was not aware of this so why does Cocos2d-x use pointers for everything within the engine framework